# How can I get an horizontal double loop (infinity symbol) with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-feynman

I want to get the following image, wich consists on two horizontal loops, by using Tikz (or Tikz-feynman).

[image: horizontal double loop]

I know that probably I have to use the parameter "arc", but I get very confused with it and I can not find the desired result

Comment: This looks more to a pair of glasses than to the infinity symbol… ;-)

Comment: You should always show what you have tried - even if it is just a compilable document with a single line or circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-1,0) circle[radius=0.1];
\fill (1,0) circle[radius=0.1];
\draw[very thick] (-1,0) to[out=55, in=125, looseness=1.5] (0,0) to[out=-55, in=-125, looseness=1.5] (1,0);
\draw[very thick] (-1,0) to[out=-55, in=-125, looseness=1.5] (0,0) to[out=55, in=125, looseness=1.5] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Infinity symbol]